# Is there a way to redirect all stdout and stderr to systemd journal from within script?

Tags: bash, logging, stdout, stderr, systemd-journald

I like the idea of using systemd's journal to view and manage the logs of my own scripts.  I have become aware you can log to journal from my user scripts on a per message basis..

```
echo 'hello' | systemd-cat -t myscript -p emerg
```

Is there a way to redirect all messages to journald, even those generated by other commands?  Like..

```
exec &> systemd-cat
```

**Update:**

Some partial success.
Tried [Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian)'s suggestion from terminal.

```
~/scripts/myscript.sh 2>&1 | systemd-cat -t myscript.sh
```

and it worked, stdout and stderr were directed to systemd's journal. 
 Curiously,

```
~/scripts/myscript.sh &> | systemd-cat -t myscript.sh
```

didn't work in my Bash terminal.

I still need to find a way to do this inside my script for when other programs call my script.

I tried..

```
exec 2>&1 | systemd-cat -t myscript.sh
```

but it doesn't work.

**Update 2**:

From terminal

```
systemd-cat ~/scripts/myscript.sh
```

works.  But I'm still looking for a way to do this from within the script.

Comment: Which application generates these logs? A shell script or another  user application?

Comment: from my personal shell scripts

Comment: Is running it as `your-script.sh &> | systemd-cat -t myscript` not working?

Comment: hmmm.  I didn't try that...

Comment: It isn't working.  `~/scripts/test.sh &> | systemd-cat -t test.sh
bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`|'`

Comment: Not sure where the error is from, may be instead of `&>`, could you try `~/scripts/test.sh 2>&1 | systemd-cat -t test.sh`

Comment: Yeah wow that worked.  Forgot I wasn't using bash in the terminal.  Thanks.  Is there a way to do this inside the script?  Because, for example, I have a torrent-done-script in Transmission and I'm not sure I can give it that command.  I'll try though.

Comment: `&> |` is not well-defined redirection syntax. (Some version of?) Bash 4 has `|&` for what you are apparently trying to say. I don't see why you'd want to use that instead of the portable and reasonably transparent `2>&1 |` though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pipe to `systemd-cat` is a process which needs to run concurrently with your script.  Bash offers a facility for this, though it's not portable to POSIX `sh`.

```
exec > >(systemd-cat -t myscript -p emerg) 2>&1
```

The `>(command)` process substitution starts another process and returns a pseudo-filename (something like `/dev/fd/63`) which you can redirect into.  This is basically a wrapper for the `mkfifo` hacks you could do if you wanted to port this to POSIX `sh`.

Comment: You can use your script path as the tag: ```-t $(realpath "$0")```
You can set a different priority for your stderr: ```2> >(... -p err)```
Resulting into:
```exec > >(systemd-cat -t "$(realpath "$0")" -p info ) 2> >(systemd-cat -t "$(realpath "$0")" -p err )```

Answer (score 1):

If your script happens to not be a shell script, but some other programming language that allows loading extension modules linked to `-lsystemd`, there is another way. There is a library function [`sd_journal_stream_fd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_journal_stream_fd.html) that quite precisely matches the task at hand. Calling it from bash itself (as opposed to some child) seems difficult at best. In Python for instance, it is available as `systemd.journal.stream`. What this function does in essence is connecting a unix domain stream socket and communicating what kind of data is being transmitted (e.g. priority). The difficult part with a shell here is making it connect a unix domain socket (as opposed to connecting in a child).

The key idea to this answer was given by Freenode/libera.chat user `grawity`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, and for reasons that are beyond me, you can't really redirect all stdout and stderr to journald from within a script because it has to be piped in.  To work around that I found a trick people were using with syslog's logger which works similarly.

You can wrap all your code into a function and then pipe the function into systemd-cat.

```
#!/bin/bash

mycode(){
  echo "hello world"
  echor "echo typo producing error"
}
mycode | systemd-cat -t myscript.sh

exit 0
```

And then to search journal logs..

```
journalctl -t myscript.sh --since yesterday
```

I'm disappointed there isn't a more direct way of doing this.